# edit style properties of label without ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website whose HTML and CSS I don't have access to.

I need to hide the label in the code below.

```
<div id ="area" class="dhx_cal_lsection">
  "Text"
  <label class="dhx_fullday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="full_day" value="true">
    "Text"
  </label>
</div>
```

`document.getElementById()` won't work because it doesn't have an ID.

I tried `document.getElementsByClassName("dhx_fullday")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";` but it said  "cannot access visibility of undefined" in the console.

Edit: Turns out the reason it couldn't access visibility of "dhx_fullday" was because it wasn't loaded at the time of execution.

Comment: I tried `document.getElementsByClassName("dhx_fullday")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";` from your post and it's working

Comment: Yes I wondered why it didn't work on my project. Turns out the dhx_fullday label wasn't loaded at the time of execution, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to select a single element from the DOM with JavaScript, using [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will do the trick. There is no need to return a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) or static (not live) [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) to select a single element. Since you can't use `getElementById` because the `<label>` doesn't have an `id`, just utilize `querySelector()` to select the label element and hide it. Or hide the content in a more accessible manner for those using assistive technologies with the [clip-pattern](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-11-how-to-hide-content/).

You could hide the `<label>` in a few different ways:

1. Add inline style directly like `element.style.display = "none"`
2. Create a CSS class to add, ie `.hide { display: none }` and then `element.classList.add("hide")`

```js
const label = document.querySelector(".dhx_fullday");
label.style.display = "none"; /* basic example */
```

```html
<div id ="area" class="dhx_cal_lsection">
  "Text"
  <label class="dhx_fullday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="full_day" value="true">
    "Text in label"
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dhx_fullday")[0].style.display = "none"
```